# Digitize numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two vectors:

```
  time_vec = np.array([0.2,0.23,0.3,0.4,0.5,...., 28....])
  values_vec = np.array([500,200,220,250,200,...., 218....])
  time_vec.shape == values_vec.shape
```

Now, I want to take the bin the values for every 0.5 second interval and take the mean of the values. So for example

```
  value_vec = np.array(mean_of(500,200,220,250,200), mean_of(next values in next 0.5 second interval))
```

Is there any numpy method I am missing which bin and take mean of the bins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`np.ufunc.reduceat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html#numpy.ufunc.reduceat). You just need to populate where the breaking points are, i.e. when `floor(t / .5)` changes:

say for:

```
>>> t
array([ 0.    ,  0.025 ,  0.2125,  0.2375,  0.2625,  0.3375,  0.475 ,  0.6875,  0.7   ,  0.7375,  0.8   ,  0.9   ,
        0.925 ,  1.05  ,  1.1375,  1.15  ,  1.1625,  1.1875,  1.1875,  1.225 ])
>>> b
array([ 0.8144,  0.3734,  1.4734,  0.6307, -0.611 , -0.8762,  1.6064,  0.3863, -0.0103, -1.6889, -0.4328, -0.7373,
        1.7856,  0.8938, -1.1574, -0.4029, -0.4352, -0.4412, -1.7819, -0.3298])
```

the break points are:

```
>>> i = np.r_[0, 1 + np.nonzero(np.diff(np.floor(t / .5)))[0]]
>>> i
array([ 0,  7, 13])
```

and the sum over each interval is:

```
>>> np.add.reduceat(b, i)
array([ 3.411 , -0.6975, -3.6545])
```

and the mean would be sum over length of interval:

```
>>> np.add.reduceat(b, i) / np.diff(np.r_[i, len(b)])
array([ 0.4873, -0.1162, -0.5221])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a `weights=` parameter to [`np.histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) to compute the summed values within each time bin, then normalize by the bin count:

```
# 0.5 second time bins to average within
tmin = time_vec.min()
tmax = time_vec.max()
bins = np.arange(tmin - (tmin % 0.5), tmax - (tmax % 0.5) + 0.5,  0.5)

# summed values within each bin
bin_sums, edges = np.histogram(time_vec,bins=bins, weights=values_vec)

# number of values within each bin
bin_counts, edges = np.histogram(time_vec,bins=bins)

# average value within each bin
bin_means = bin_sums / bin_counts
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) that is supposedly pretty efficient for such binning operations. Here's an implementation based on it to solve our case -

```
# Find indices where 0.5 intervals shifts onto next ones
A = time_vec*2
idx = np.searchsorted(A,np.arange(1,int(np.ceil(A.max()))),'right')

# Setup ID array such that all 0.5 intervals are ID-ed same
out = np.zeros((A.size),dtype=int)
out[idx[idx < A.size]] = 1
ID = out.cumsum()

# Finally use bincount to sum and count elements of same IDs
# and thus get mean values per ID
mean_vec = np.bincount(ID,values_vec)/np.bincount(ID)
```

Sample run -

```
In [189]: time_vec
Out[189]: 
array([ 0.2 ,  0.23,  0.3 ,  0.4 ,  0.5 ,  0.7 ,  0.8 ,  0.92,  0.95,
        1.  ,  1.11,  1.5 ,  2.  ,  2.3 ,  2.5 ,  4.5 ])

In [190]: values_vec
Out[190]: array([36, 11, 93, 32, 72, 75, 26, 28, 77, 31, 60, 77, 76, 32,  6, 85])

In [191]: ID
Out[191]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5], dtype=int32)

In [192]: mean_vec
Out[192]: array([ 48.8,  47.4,  68.5,  76. ,  19. ,  85. ])
```